# Disable home button for API level < 14

Tags: android

[ActionBar#setHomeButtonEnabled(true)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setHomeButtonEnabled%28boolean%29) is defined for api level > 14.

The doc say, "`This defaults to true for packages targeting < API 14`".
How can I disable the Home button for earlier versions. Currently if I press the home button in action bar, the screen refreshes.

I like to support Version 13, so my config is.

```
 android:minSdkVersion="13"
 android:targetSdkVersion="15"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using the popular open source library [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/).  It supports an ActionBar using the ActionBar API from ICS (API level 14), but backports all the way back to API Level 7 (aka 2.1).

This will let you use setHomeButtonEnabled() and the rest of the ActionBar API from API Level 7 to the latest, which is currently API Level 16.